# Deriving or mapping weblogic.xml from web.xml

Tags: spring-mvc, weblogic

I am trying to deploy a springMVC Hibernate project to webLogic 10.3.5 and I cannot figure out what I need in my weblogic.xml. It works perfectly in tomcat 6 and I initially had issue deploying to websphere but I was able to resolve that with the weblogic.xml:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
    <context-root>myproject</context-root>
    <container-descriptor>
      <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
  </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Now that it is deployed, I have no images or css or any of my jsp pages other then the main page. I tried to following the [weblogic Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13712/weblogic_xml.htm) but found it very confusing.

Is there any resources or can any one explain to me what I need to to add to this. For Reference here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
  <display-name>My Project</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myproject-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myproject-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and this is my myproject-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean name="/index.html" 
    class="com.fid.mdc.admin.controller.AdminController" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

as I mentioned, this all works perfectly in tomcat 6 as is, so I just need some help to understand how I translate this to weblogic 10.3.5

Comment: Did you try giving url-pattern as '/*' instead of just '/' ?

Comment: @Mani that unfortunately cause more issues, I then cannot access the index page